# Sum of $\sum_{i=0}^n k^i$ when $k=1$

Tags: summation

I have this sequence as a function of $n$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n k^i$$
which is equal to
$$\frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}$$

for each $k\in\Bbb{Z}\backslash\{1\}$.
For $k=1$, the above formula returns $\frac00$.
Is there any formula which solves my problem?

**Edit:** I am looking for a general formula which contains the $k=1$ case rather than making a case-by-case analysis.

Comment: For $k=1$, the answer is $n+1$.

Comment: Would you consider $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n k^i=\begin{cases}\tfrac{k ^{n+1}-1}{k-1},&k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{1\}\\n+1, &k=1\end{cases}$ to be a satisfactory formula?

Comment: Or $\lim_{x \to k} \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1}$.

Comment: @Workaholic I am sorry for not mentioning that I tried to avoid a case-by-case analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to compute $$\lim_{k\to 1}\frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: But really, for $k=1$ the sum is just $\sum_{i=0}^n 1$.

Comment: @ClementC. yeah, that's funny. But taking a limit at least illustrates that we can assign a value to this function at $k=1$

Comment: My only formula would then be $\lim_{a\to k}\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$

Answer (score 2):

When $k=1$, your series becomes

$$\sum \limits _{i=0} ^n 1^i = \sum \limits _{i=0} ^n 1 = \underset {n + 1 \text{ times}} {\underbrace {1 + 1 + \dots + 1}} = n + 1 ,$$

so for this case you need no formula, the result being straightforward.

Comment: I have come up with that too. But I'd have to make separate case for k=1. I was actually looking for a general formula (Sorry for being imprecise in my question)

Comment: @xoxox: There is no such general formula. No matter how you try to run away from it and hide it under layers of abstraction, $k=1$ will always be a separate case, as you and the other respondents have shown - precisely for the reason noted by you yourself.